# how to define a string as a directory in vba

Tags: vba, outlook

I need to set a directory, but I need it to be variable.
in below example, I want to Create a Folder with the name of my Email subject. And then set the path to the created folder.
with below script it does not save my emails to folder i created. Would you please help?

```
N1 = oMail.Subject
On Error Resume Next
MkDir "C:\Users\meti\Desktop\E" & N1
On Error GoTo 0

sPath = "C:\Users\meti\Desktop\E" & N1
Debug.Print sPath & sName
oMail.SaveAs sPath & sName, olMSG
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What you are trying to do is always going to be problematic, as you can't rely on an email subject being 'safe' - for example, what if it contains a back-slash character, or a quote?

Comment: Yes you can, can you show more off your code or complete code please...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all, I found a way. if there is any better way please give me your comment, I'd appreciate it.

```
On Error Resume Next
MkDir "C:\Users\mwx391225\Desktop\Email" & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy h-mm")
On Error GoTo 0

sPath = "C:\Users\mwx391225\Desktop\Email" & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy h-mm") & "\"
Debug.Print sPath & sName
oMail.SaveAs sPath & sName, olMSG
```

Comment: Just before MkDir create a staticNow = Now. Replace Now in your code with staticNow.